# Qt5: dynamic add QLabel from buttom to the top

Tags: qt5, qwidget

I'm using QVboxLayout to achieve this.
The following code below is what I'm currently trying:

```
BubbleLabel *label = new BubbleLabel();
label->setText(text);
ui->verticalLayout->insertWidget(-1, label);
```

Instead of from buttom to the top, the result was from top to buttom:
[image]

I want it to show this way:
[image]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Insert works with the 'placement location' as index.
You should use:

```
ui->verticalLayout->insertWidget(0, label);
```

Comment: No, this still does not let the QLabel display from the buttom to the top

Comment: please submit a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)